# AWS Personalize - HPO - solutionConfig

Tags: amazon-personalize

I have incorporated the solutionConfig as part of HPO in AWS personlaize service.
solutionConfig = {
"optimizationObjective": {
"itemAttribute": "ITEM_WEIGHT",
"objectiveSensitivity": "HIGH"
},

I am getting the following error
Unknown parameter in solutionConfig: "optimizationObjective", must be one of: eventValueThreshold, hpoConfig, algorithmHyperParameters, featureTransformationParameters, autoMLConfig]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be using a version of the AWS SDK that does not include support for the `optimizationObjective` parameter of the solution config. Check to make sure that you're using the latest version of the AWS SDK.

Comment: Hi James...Thanks for your advise...But I am using the latest version.  Also I tried using all the parameters and still I am getting the same error.